# Jenkins JobConfigHistory Plugin - XML Parsing Error: no element found - Not showing Diffs

Tags: plugins, jenkins, history, jobs

I installed JobConfigHistory plugin in Jenkins instance running as Windows service. Jenkins is running fine.

I made changes to a job's configuration i.e. added some text.

On the left pane Job's dashboard page, I clicked on "Job Config History" link.

That opened a new page on the right pane, with the following info:

Job Configuration History

**GigaWebFiles**

```
Date            Opertion User   Show File           Restore old config Diff 
                                                                       File A File B
2012-11-27_x_x  Changed  c9807  View as XML  (RAW)                             (*)
2012-11-27_x_x  Changed  c9807  View as XML  (RAW)  Restore             (*)
```

There's a "Show Diffs" button just above this info, I clicked it, nothing is showing up.

When I click on the "View as XML" link, it gives me the following error.

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://jenkins06.server.com:8080/job/GigaWebFiles/jobConfigHistory/configOutput?type=xml&file=D%3A%5Cjenkins04%5Ctomcat6%5Cbin%5C..%5C..%5Cjenkins%5Cconfig-history%5Cjobs%5CGigaWebFiles%5C2012-11-27_19-49-31
Line Number 2, Column 1:
^
```

Any idea what needs to be corrected. 


I tried uninstalling the plugin "JobConfigHistory" (by removing the .hpi and folders under JENKINS_HOME/plugins folder and saved all the jobs in Jenkins instance again (to remove any references to this plugin).


I'm also seeing the following Jenkins SYSTEM log during instance restart.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: D:\jenkins04\tomcat6\bin\..\..\jenkins\config-history\jobs\GigaWebFiles\2012-11-27_19-49-31 does not start with D:\jenkins04\tomcat6\bin\..\..\jenkins\config-history or contains '..'
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.getConfigXml(JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.java:158)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.getFile(JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.java:114)
    ... 85 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: D:\jenkins04\tomcat6\bin\..\..\jenkins\config-history\jobs\GigaWebFiles\2012-11-27_19-49-31 does not start with D:\jenkins04\tomcat6\bin\..\..\jenkins\config-history or contains '..'
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.getConfigXml(JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.java:158)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.getDiffFile(JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.java:257)
    at hudson.plugins.jobConfigHistory.JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.getDiffLines(JobConfigHistoryBaseAction.java:273)
    ... 123 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the maintainers of the JobConfigHistory plugin. I only found your question here by chance, issues for this plugin should be opened in the Jenkins Jira:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS/component/15683

The problem is that the plugin right now for security reasons doesn't accept paths which contain '..'. This issue will probably be fixed with one of the next releases.